# Authorization based on assigned Permission function

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have three **tables** 
 `dbo.PermissionFunc`, `dbo.Roles`, `dbo.Permissions` for my `asp.net MVC web application`.

`dbo.PermissionFunc` contains all the function name in my project.
`dbo.Roles` contains the user roles such as admin, user, subuser etc
`dbo.Permissions` contains the `RolesId` from `dbo.Roles` and `PermissionFuncId` from `dbo.PermissionFunc`.
I want to give `authorization` based on the value assigned in `dbo.Permission`.

[image: Image shows the assigning permission to the role]

> Update in question:
>   **Query using to determine if the current user has  permission or not**

```
        string mail = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
        var usr = _user.GetUserByMail(mail);
        var permFunc = _permissionfunc.FindByName("ActionResultName");
        var permission = _permission.checkIfPermitted(Convert.ToInt64(usr.Usr_Role_ID), permFunc.PermFunc_ID);//usr.Usr_Role_ID is RoleId and permFunc.PermFunc_ID is the PermissionFunctionId
        if(permission != null)
        {
              //Permission granted
        }
        else
        {
             //Permission Rejected
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure what you are really after. By the description it looks like you need to code functionalities against the permission id and call generic reusable code to evaluate what permission ids the logged in user resolves through the role and then  make a judgement on what (hide/show/readonly etc) can be done with the functionalities .

Comment: @Lin I want to autherize the function based on value assigned in `dbo.Permission`.

Comment: What table maps permissions to functions (dbo.PermissionFunc)?

Comment: @Lin `dbo.Permission` contains the `RolesId` from `dbo.Roles` and `PermissionFuncId` from `dbo.PermissionFunc`

Comment: Ok. bit confusing name, i assumed permission to be a master data. guessing from the tag you are trying to implement something in asp.netmvc to facilitate access to functions ? I am guessing a lot. give clear details on to what you are trying to acheive. The answer you got below from Aspirin probably do the job if you are after an MVC wrapper

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be if a user with say 'View', but not 'Edit' permissions to be if they navigate to the `Edit()` method - do you want then to be directed to a page displaying an error message explaining they do not have that permission?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if a user has  permission for view() but no Edit(), then it want to redirect to a custom page.

Comment: OK, And what is the query you use to determine if the current user has a specific table and permission - for example if the user navigated to the `Edit()` method of `TaxController`? (that at least should be included in your question so that the code in an answer makes sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment. Now the question is updated with **Query using to determine if the current user has permission or not**

Comment: Still not clear what your query is actually returning, or what `FunctionName` is. Does that have a relationship to the ActionResult and Controller name

Comment: A custom AuthorizationAttribute would not be appropriate (the user is already authorized, and you would not want them to be logging in again if they did not have permission for a specific action). You could of course add the code to check the permission in each controller method, but using an `ActionFilter` would be the better option.

Comment: To do that you would need to pass a parameter that identifies what parameters need to be passed in your query (e.g. it might look like [ValidatePermissions("EditTax")]` where "EditTax" is your FunctionName) although it would be easier to follow conventions so you could just do `[ValidatePermissions]` and use the current controller and method names to determine the query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that worked for the above question is here:

> AuthorizationController

```
#region CustomAuthorizationAttribute
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    private PermissionRepository _permission = new PermissionRepository();
    private PermissionFuncRepository _permissionFun = new PermissionFuncRepository();


    // roles start
    public string IdentityRoles
    {
        get { return _permissionName ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _permissionName = value;
        }
    }

    private string _permissionName;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //do the base class AuthorizeCore first

        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string RoleID = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(httpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name.Split('|')[1];
            var permisionID = _permissionFun.FindByName(_permissionName);
            if(permisionID != null)
            {
                var permis = _permission.GetPermission().Where(a => a.Perm_PermFuncID == permisionID.PermFunc_ID && a.Perm_RollID.ToString() == RoleID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (permis != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //if the user is not logged in use the deafult HandleUnauthorizedRequest and redirect to the login page
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        //if the user is logged in but is trying to access a page he/she doesn't have the right for show the access denied page
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/AccessDenied");
        }
    }


}
#endregion
```

> Foreach ActionController, I accessed these Authorization as follows:

```
    [CustomAuthorization(IdentityRoles = "AdjustmentsView")]
    public ActionResult AdjustmentIndex()
    {
        var adjlist = _Adj.GetAdjustmentHead();
        List<AdjustmentHeadViewModel> adjustlist = new List<AdjustmentHeadViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in adjlist)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AdjustmentHead, AdjustmentHeadViewModel>());
            AdjustmentHeadViewModel entity = Mapper.Map<AdjustmentHead, AdjustmentHeadViewModel>(item);
            adjustlist.Add(entity);
        }
        return View(adjustlist);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create [custom AuthorizationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the logic of checking your roles and permissions in it and use it for operations that requires that.

You can use [mvc.filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) with your  implementation of `IAuthorizationFilter`, to filter every request. Register it in your `FilterConfig`

```
filters.Add(new MyAuthorizationAttribute());
```

Comment: There is an Autherization function. How I can accesses that function for each ActionResult from controller

Comment: You can use mvc.filters with your implementation of `IAuthorizationFilter` to filter every request

Answer (score 2):

Updated to use CustomAuthorize attribute on MVC action

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _action { get; set; }

    public CustomAuthorize() { }
    public CustomAuthorize(string action) { _action = action; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User == null)
            return false;

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        // HasPermission function implements looking up by user name and action
        // to see if user has a role that would give them access to this action
        return PermissionChecker.HasPermission(httpContext.User.Identity.Name, _action);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // handle unauthorized requests here
        // return 503 error or whatever
    }

}


// example of using custom attribute in MVC controller action
[HttpGet]
[CustomAuthorize("View")]
public ActionResult MyActionActualViewMethodName()
{
    var result = {
        id = 1,
        name = ""
    };
    return Json(result);
}

[HttpDelete]
[CustomAuthorize("Delete")]
public ActionResult MyActionActualDeleteMethodName(int id)
{
    // do delete action
    return Json(true);
}


// static permission checker implementation    
public static class PermissionChecker
{
    static List<GenericIdNameClass> users = new List<GenericIdNameClass>() {
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 2, Name = "Bob" },
    };

    static List<GenericIdNameClass> roles = new List<GenericIdNameClass>() {
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 10, Name = "User" },
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 11, Name = "Admin" },
    };

    static List<GenericIdNameClass> actions = new List<GenericIdNameClass>() {
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 100, Name = "View" },
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 101, Name = "Create/Edit" },
        new GenericIdNameClass { Id = 102, Name = "Delete" },
    };

    static List<GenericEntityRelationClass> roleActionMappings = new List<GenericEntityRelationClass>() {
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 10, Id2 = 100 },
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 11, Id2 = 100 },
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 11, Id2 = 101 },
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 11, Id2 = 102 },
    };

    // John only has User role, Bob has User and Admin
    static List<GenericEntityRelationClass> userRoleMappings = new List<GenericEntityRelationClass>() {
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 1, Id2 = 10 },
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 2, Id2 = 10 },
        new GenericEntityRelationClass{ Id1 = 2, Id2 = 11 },
    };

    public static bool HasPermission(string userName, string actionName)
    {
        var user = users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == userName);
        if (user == null)
            return false;

        var action = actions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == actionName);
        if (action == null)
            return false;

        var userRoles = userRoleMappings.Where(x => x.Id1 == user.Id).Select(x => x.Id2).ToList();

        return roleActionMappings.Any(x => userRoles.Contains(x.Id1) && x.Id2 == action.Id);
    }

    public class GenericIdNameClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenericEntityRelationClass
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. But this is not an answer to my question. Role assigning is already perfectly working. I want the authorization based on the  assigned role and permission.

Comment: The solution posted. Refer if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Alsamil,

If you have time, please read about the new way Microsoft is doing [Claims-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims)

And if you have even more time, I really recommend you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJeZ3YNnqz8) conference. Dominick Baier & Brock Allen are really known in the security industry and they explain how to do Authorisation in a really nice way which is related to the [Claims-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims) article. If I am not wrong they are the minds behind this new way of authorisation.

Comment: The solution posted. Refer if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute and tag your actions with it.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RequireFunction : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _function;

    public RequireFunction(string func) { _function = func; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User == null)
            return false;

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        // modified code sample from question
        string mail = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var user = _user.GetUserByMail(mail);
        var permFunc = _permissionfunc.FindByName(_function);
        var permission = _permission.checkIfPermitted(Convert.ToInt64(usr.Usr_Role_ID), permFunc.PermFunc_ID);
        return permission != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution posted. Refer if you need.